# Retrieving the output of a function that returns an array in C++

Tags: c++, function, dynamic-arrays

How can I retrieve the output of the following function so that I can use it.

my code:

```
#include <iostream>
    #include <iomanip>
    #include <complex>
    #include <cmath>
    #include <cstddef>

    double binFreq(int n)
         {
            int j;
            double* f = new double[n];

            for ( j = 0 ; j < n ; j++ ){

            f[j] =(fmod(j+(floor(n/2)), n)-floor(n/2))/n;
            //std::cout << "f["<<j<<"] ="<<f[j] <<std::endl;
            }
            delete [] f;
         }

    int main()
    {   

        int n=9;
        double* F=new double [n];
        F[n]=binFreq(n);

        for ( int i = 0 ; i < n ; ++i ){ 
        std::cout << "F["<<i<<"] ="<<F[i] <<std::endl;
        }


    }
```

As you can see in the code above , I have tried but I am getting all zeros for each element:

```
Output:

F[0] =0
F[1] =0
F[2] =0
F[3] =0
F[4] =0
F[5] =0
F[6] =0
F[7] =0
F[8] =0
```

Modified code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstddef>
#include <vector>

std::vector<double> binFreq(int n)
{
   int j;
   std::vector<double> f(n);

   for ( j = 0 ; j < n ; j++ ){

      f[j] =(fmod(j+(floor(n/2)), n)-floor(n/2))/n;
   }
   return f;
}

int main()
{   

    int n=9;
    double* F;
    F=binFreq(n);

    for ( int i = 0 ; i < n ; ++i ){ 
    std::cout << "F["<<i<<"] ="<<F[i] <<std::endl;
    }

}
```

I am getting new error
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:23:16: error: cannot convert 'std::vector' to 'double*' in assignment
     F=binFreq(n);

Comment: To begin with, `binFreq` doesn't return anything, leading to *undefined behavior*. To continue, in the `main` function when you do `F[n] = ...` you are writing out of bounds of the allocated memory *again* leading to undefined behavior. Lastly, shouldn't the `binFreq` function return a pointer, i.e. `F`?

Comment: Just use a `std::vector<int>` when programming seriously in c++.

Comment: Pick a language; C or C++. There's no "C/C++" language.

Comment: Change `F` type from `double *` to `std::vector<double>` as well. Or better `auto` for C++11 or later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better to avoid returning an array. Return a `std::vector` instead.
It is less error prone than using arrays. Also, dynamic memory management is taken care of for you.

```
std::vector<double> binFreq(int n)
{
   int j;
   std::vector<double> f(n);

   for ( j = 0 ; j < n ; j++ ){

      f[j] =(fmod(j+(floor(n/2)), n)-floor(n/2))/n;
   }
   return f;
}
```

You'll need to modify `main` to reflect the return value of the function.

```
int main()
{   
   int n = 9;
   auto F = binFreq(n);
   for ( int i = 0 ; i < n ; ++i )
   { 
      std::cout << "F["<<i<<"] ="<<F[i] <<std::endl;
   }
}
```

Comment: @R Sahu, I have modify code using vector as you suggested , but now I am getting a new error message :  error: cannot convert 'std::vector<double>' to 'double*' in assignment
     F=binFreq(n);

Comment: @Serge, use `auto F = binFreq(n);`. Don't use `int* F`.

Comment: @Serge, sure. Glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 0):

You should create the array F inside your function (as you do), but then not delete it, rather return it.
`return f;` instead of `delete [] f;`

Then in your main function, just declare F as `double* F` and use the assignement `F = binFreq(n);`

That way, you create the array inside of your function, and you return a pointer to it. Then from your main, you assign that pointer to F and you can then use your array.

Don't forget to delete the array at the end of your main!

Comment: Returning a raw pointer to dynamically allocated memory  is a really bad idea and pretty straight way to disaster, though it was not my downvote

Comment: Because it is extremely easy to ignore result of a function call which will lead to a memory leak in this case. So such function should at least return a smart pointer, but better `std::vector` or `std::array`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also give a reference to a vector:

```
void binFreq(std::vector<double> &freq, int n)
{
    freq.resize(n,0.0) ;
    for (int j = 0 ; j < n ; j++ )
    {
        f[j] =(fmod(j+(floor(n/2)), n)-floor(n/2))/n;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n=9 ;
    std::vector<double> F ;
    binFreq(F,n) ;

    return 0 ;

}
```